# Query a Sub Query with IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to get student's religion (agama) data which is distributed based on the year of registration. The student's religion is recognized by the class of subjects chosen by the student

Please tell me, what's wrong in my query with sub query

```
SELECT 
  `subject_name` agama, 
  SUM(IF(YEAR(`reg_date`)=2017,1,0)) ts3,
  SUM(IF(YEAR(`reg_date`)=2018,1,0)) ts2,
  SUM(IF(YEAR(`reg_date`)=2019,1,0)) ts1,
  SUM(IF(YEAR(`reg_date`)=2020,1,0)) ts
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `st`.`reg_id`, `st`.`stname`, `st`.`reg_date`, `sj`.`subject_name`
    FROM `students` `st` 
    LEFT JOIN `class` `cl` USING (`reg_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `subject` `sj` USING (`subject_id`)
    WHERE `st`.`status` = 'A'
    AND `sj`.`subject_name` LIKE '%agama%')
```

I've got syntax error and point to the end of query

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 13

if I run the sub query separately, I get a table of students with their religion as I want, but not divided by year of registration.

I think there's a rule I don't know about sub-queries in SQL (MySQL)

### Updated:

sample table that I need to create:

```
Agama      2017  2018  2019  2020
---------------------------------
Islam       18    11     15   12
Kristen     20    18      7   12
Katholik    22    26     11   16
Hindu        2     0      0    0
Buddha      28    26     16   20
```

sample result for sub query if run separately

```
reg_id      stname                    reg_date     subject_name
---------+-------------------------+-------------+----------------------------
52017032    YOSUA MARCELL RUHUKAIL   2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA KRISTEN
52017035    HESTI ERINA TOBEOTO      2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA KRISTEN
52017014    GERALDI RADITYO WIWONO   2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA KATHOLIK
52017026    RIVALDO WINENGKO         2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA KATHOLIK
52017009    ARFIANDO KARSON EUGENA   2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA BUDDHA
52017016    HO LUSI                  2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA BUDDHA
52017027    RONALD KWANDY            2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA BUDDHA
52017031    YESSY                    2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA BUDDHA
51017002    ALIFKA GAUNG H           2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA ISLAM
51017003    AYU ARIYANINGSIH         2017-09-18    PENDIDIKAN AGAMA ISLAM
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Derived table requires an ***alias***. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: Thank you, @PM77-1, it works after put alias name and group by statement. Please write your suggestion as an answer and I will vote as right answer